# Thunar not displaying thumbnails for text files

Tags: 12.04, thunar, thumbnails

I have gone through all other posts on thunar thumbnailing issue but this one doesn't seem to match any of those; nor on the web anyone seems to have this problem, so I couldn't find solution on google either.
Also, I have the following packages installed - thunar (version 1.2.3), tumbler. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 [updated].

This is what I expect (pic from nautilus) -
[image]

This is what I am getting (pic from thunar itself) -
[image]

Thunar is much better than nautilus in all expects, but for small ones like this one. Kindly help.